# Optimización tiempo mandar varios email a la vez con php, tarda mucho

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Cuento con un formulario con el que el usuario selecciona varios ids para poder traer todos los usuarios asociados a ellos.

Sin embargo, el codigo que estoy utilizando tarda mucho en ejecutarse por completo (1 min y pico en ocasiones) al estar utilizando un foreach y resulta que no permite salir de esa vista hasta que se ha ejecutado por completo.

Tengo una clase Email.php donde en el _construct he definido los campos para la variable $email.

Si alguien sabe una forma para poder optimizar el tiempo de envío de los correos o alguna forma alternativa, se lo agradezco.

```
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        $posgrado = $_POST['posgradoId'];
        $lenguaPartida = $_POST['lenguaPartidaId'];
        $lenguaMeta = $_POST['lenguaMetaId'];
        $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
        $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
        $archivo = $_FILES['fichero'];
        
        if($lenguaPartida == null) $lenguaPartida = '%';
        if($lenguaMeta == null) $lenguaMeta = '%';

        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT usuarios.nombre, usuarios.email, alumPosgrado.alumnoId, alumPosgrado.posgradoId, posgrados.nombrePosgrado
        FROM alumPosgrado
        LEFT JOIN usuarios ON alumPosgrado.alumnoId = usuarios.id
        LEFT JOIN posgrados ON alumPosgrado.posgradoId = posgrados.id
        WHERE posgrados.id = {$posgrado}
        AND (lenguaPartidaId LIKE '{$lenguaPartida}' and lenguaMetaId LIKE '{$lenguaMeta}');";
        
        $alumPosgrados = AlumPosgrado::SQL($query);

        foreach($alumPosgrados as $alumPosgrado){

            $email = new Email($alumPosgrado->email, $alumPosgrado->nombre, '', '', '', '', '', '', $asunto, $mensaje, $archivo); // Esto nos crea un nuevo objeto $email

            $email->emailPosgrado();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Creo que en tu código hay poco para optimizar. Lo que podrías hacer es ejecutar el envío de correo en un proceso separado.

Comment: Gracias por responder @Yussef. ¿A que te refieres con realizar el envío de correo un proceso separado?

Comment: Yo tuve el mismo caso tuyo (pero con asp.net) y lo que hice fue crear un programa de consola que enviaba lo correos y desde el asp ejecutaba el programa de consola, así el servidor web se liberaba. En php existe la función `exec` con la que creo puede hacer lo mismo. Echale un ojo a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148388/creating-new-thread-in-php (incluido los enlaces que están en la pregunta)

Comment: También podrías agendar el envio en lotes para evitar que te bloqueen por SPAM. Por ejemplo, si envias muchos mails Gmail vas a tener problemas ya que existe [una cantidad por minuto que Gmail acepta](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126).

Comment: De acuerdo @Yussef, gracias, voy a echarle un vistazo.

Comment: @Marcos agendar el envío por lotes evitaría que la web se quedara 'cargando' y pudiera el usuario utilizarla mientras se envían por lotes?

Comment: @robertuno, claro, ya que no intentarias enviar miles de mails al mismo tiempo sino unos cientos (_o menos_) por minuto. Tambien evitarias llenar la cola de envios del servidor.

Comment: @Marcos cómo se podría hacer el envío por lotes?